# Create new element with jQuery and set style immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) of jQuery to create new elements and adding attributes directly. This work fine in general. But I'm unable to add `style` attribute in a proper way.

For example, this works fine:

```
$container.append($("<div />", {class: 'some-class'}));
```

I've tried to add the `style` attribute, like I would do with `data` attributes. But this doesn't work in any way.

```
$container.append($("<div />", {
    class: 'some-class',
    style: {
        width: 100,
        background: '#f00'
    }
}));
```

Is there any way to set the `style` directly on creation of new elements with **this syntax**?

Comment: Whats wrong with the question for the downvoters? Please tell me.

Comment: you have to use $.parseHTML for styling in append like this http://jsfiddle.net/gp5Leg2v/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `style` to `css`:

```js
$('body').append($("<div />", {
    class: 'some-class',
    css: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        background: '#f00'
    }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.css()` function to set or alter the Style attribute. Or you need to give the style attribute a single string as argument instead of an object. jQuery does not parse an object to a string except in specialized functions like the `.css()` function.

To Specify:
With

```
var $container = $('body');
$container.append($("<div/>", {
    class: 'some-class',
    css: {
        'width': '100',
        'background': '#f00'
    }
}));
```

You call the css function on creation of the element with your object as parameter.
With

```
var $container = $('body');
$container.append($("<div/>", {
    class: 'some-class',
    style: 'width:100px;background:#f00;'
    }
}));
```

You'll initialize the style attribute with a single string. Since Style is a property of the element and not a function, it cannot handle an object as parameter

Comment: @eisbehr my answer is perfectly compatible with your syntax. You either give your object in the css function as SWC noted, or you have to give the style property a single string as value instead of an object.

Comment: @eisbehr I elaborated a little, maybe this'll make it clearer

Comment: Way better now!

Answer (score -1):

you can add like this

```
$( "body" ).add( "div" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: I know that, but please note that I specially ask for the given syntax in the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $container = $('body');
$container.append($("<div/>", {
    class: 'some-class',
    css: {
        'width': '100',
        'height':'100',
        'background': '#f00'
    }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't downvoted you, but it might be bcause your example snippet is not working and you posted the same answer as SWC, but 10 minutes later. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @eisbehr It wasnt visible because it just had the width attribute. I added height to it. Check it out now.

Comment: I didn't complain, i just wanted to explain the reason you might be downvoted here. ;)